# Сформировать строку из списка

Tags: python

Можно как то сформировать строку из списка без конкатенации

```
lst = [['TEST1', '1'], ['TEST2', '2'], ['TEST3', '3']]
```

Должно получится

```
st = ':0,:1,:2'
```

Пробовал так

```
st = ':,'.join([str(i) for i, row in enumerate(lst)])
```

Comment: `":"+",:".join(map(str, range(len(lst))))`

Comment: `','.join(map(':{}'.format, range(len(lst))))`.

Comment: Оба варианта подходят. Остановился на последнем. Спасибо!